# Docker Installer: gpg no valid OpenPGP data found on Windows

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am currently trying to install an application running docker-compose up, but I keep on running into the same issues:

```
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

This is the content of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN \
 apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y -q curl gnupg \
 && curl -sSL 'http://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x8AA7AF1F1091A5FD' | apt-key add -  \
 && echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/chime/stable bionic universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
 && apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read some documentation for how to run and extend Sawtooth is available [here](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/sysadmin_guide/installation.html) and [sawtooth core](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-core) on github so I build Dockerfile includes

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install gnupg -y
 
RUN \
 apt-get update \
 && echo "deb http://repo.sawtooth.me/ubuntu/nightly bionic universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list  \
 && (apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 44FC67F19B2466EA \
 || apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 44FC67F19B2466EA) \
 && apt-get update
```